# deserialize and constructor relationship

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I don't know why i can't find an easy quick lookup for this on the web but i was wondering what the relationship is between Deserializing an XML representation of an object and the constructor for that object?

I am assuming it uses the Default Constructor. And if that's the case, it will run the code in the constructor, but not update the object itself after that to reflect the XML?

Here's a bit more context on what i mean...

I have an object with two properties that are actually objects as well:

```
public class Deployment
{
    public AppPoolSettings AppPool { get; set; }
    public WebSiteSettings Site { get; set; }

    public Deployment()
    {
        //the object constructors below init their internal properties as well...
        this.AppPool = new AppPoolSettings();
        this.Site = new WebSiteSettings();
    }
}
```

The problem I am currently having is that in the XML, the `AppPool` property can be null (say, if you're deploying an HTML only package). The serialization procedure works properly, that is to say, the resulting XML only contains an entry for Site, and no entry for AppPool.

However, when I deserialize that XML, the AppPool property of my `Deployment` object is always instantiated and initialized... which is not what the XML is saying.

Am I doing something wrong or is it really just because of the default constructor?

See I would've expected the deserializer to perform the tasks in this order:
1- Call default constructor
2- Does AppPool property exist in XML?
       Yes --> Fill,
       No --> Set to NULL
3- Does the Site property exist in XML?
       Yes --> Fill,
       No --> Set to NULL

Why is it not doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct answer is: **yes, counterintuitive handling of null properties (omitting them in serialized data and doing nothing with them on deserialization) is a feature of `XmlSerializer`**. But you can override that behavior and force XmlSerializer to write nulls to XML with attributes like that:

```
public class Deployment
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public AppPoolSettings AppPool { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public WebSiteSettings Site { get; set; }

    public Deployment()
    {
        //the object constructors below init their internal properties as well...
        this.AppPool = new AppPoolSettings();
        this.Site = new WebSiteSettings();
    }
}
```

then you'll get `<AppPool xsi:nil="true" />` in XML and expected deserialization.

Comment: if i do this, all of my calls and references to the property now have issues... `System.Nullable<AppPoolSettings> does not contain a definition for name, for Clone(), for ... all properties i ever call` ... is there a way around this? otherwise i'd have to typecast every single reference or call i've ever made in my code... which is... a LOT...

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor is called, and therefore, Site and AppPool are assigned. If you want them be `null` maybe you could try this code:

```
public class Deployment
{
     private AppPoolSettings appPool;

     public AppPoolSettings AppPool
     {
         get { return appPool; }
         set
         {
             // if (appPool == null)
             //    appPool = new AppPoolSettings();
             appPool = value;
         }
     }

     private WebSiteSettings site;

     public WebSiteSettings Site
     {
         get { return site; }
         set
         {
             // if (site == null)
             //    site = new WebSiteSettings();
             site = value;
         }
     }

     public Deployment()
     {
         // No instatiation anymore...         
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You expectations are wrong. `XmlSerializer` will construct object (by calling parameterless constructor, if there is none - exception is thrown). Then properties will be populated one by one using some reflection magic.

So what happens:

1. Constructor is called, in which you set values of `AppPool` and `Site`.
2. There is `Site` property in xml, it's deserialized and assigned.
3. But there is no `AppPool` in xml, so nothing changes and its value stay (not `null`).

To have `null` for `AppPool` you should not set its value in constructor. Then it will stay such if missing in xml.

Here is one possible solution:

```
public class Deployment
{
    public AppPoolSettings AppPool { get; set; }
    public WebSiteSettings Site { get; set; }

    // used by deserializer
    public Deployment() { }

    // use this to construct object
    public static Deployment Create()
    {
        return new Deployment()
        {
            AppPool = new AppPoolSettings(),
            Site = new WebSiteSettings()
        };
    }
}
```